# Calculate new dataframe variables with distance from column mean

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, distance, mean

I have a dataframe that look something like this.

| User | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | .34 | .33 | .88 |
| David | .54 | .34 | .71 |
| Scott | .12 | .25 | .12 |
| Frank | .76 | .76 | .44 |
| Doug | .68 | .09 | .54 |
| Tom | .91 | .67 | .92 |

But I would like to calculate a new variables. I want the new variables (`V1_DISTfromMEAN`, `V2_DISTfromMEAN`, `V3_DISTfromMEAN`) to be calculated by subtracting each observation from their corresponding variables (`V1`, `V2`, `V3`) from the column's mean value. For example, the mean for the column `V1` is .55. So for Jim, I would want the equation to be .34 - .55 = -0.21. for `V1_DISTfromMean`. The resulting dataframe would look something like the one below, with all values filled in.

| User | V1 | V2 | V3 | V1_DISTfromMEAN | V2_DISTfromMEAN | V1_DISTfromMEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | .34 | .33 | .88 | - .21 | ??? | ??? |
| David | .54 | .34 | .71 | - .01 | ??? | ??? |
| Scott | .12 | .25 | .12 | ??? | ??? | ??? |
| Frank | .76 | .76 | .44 | ??? | ??? | ??? |
| Doug | .68 | .09 | .54 | ??? | ??? | ??? |
| Tom | .91 | .67 | .92 | ??? | ??? | ??? |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Let me know if I've failed to include all the necessary data.

Comment: `data$V1_DISTfromMEAN <- data$V1 - mean(data$V1)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `colMeans` to get a vector of means, subtract from the input data set taking care that R's table operations are in column major order, bind the original with the result.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
User    V1  V2  V3
Jim     .34     .33     .88
David   .54     .34     .71
Scott   .12     .25     .12
Frank   .76     .76     .44
Doug    .68     .09     .54
Tom     .91     .67     .92
", header = TRUE)

mu <- colMeans(df1[-1])
tmp <- t(t(df1[-1]) - mu)
colnames(tmp) <- paste(colnames(tmp), "DISTfromMEAN", sep = "_")
df2 <- cbind(df1, tmp)
rm(tmp)

df2
#>    User   V1   V2   V3 V1_DISTfromMEAN V2_DISTfromMEAN V3_DISTfromMEAN
#> 1   Jim 0.34 0.33 0.88     -0.21833333     -0.07666667      0.27833333
#> 2 David 0.54 0.34 0.71     -0.01833333     -0.06666667      0.10833333
#> 3 Scott 0.12 0.25 0.12     -0.43833333     -0.15666667     -0.48166667
#> 4 Frank 0.76 0.76 0.44      0.20166667      0.35333333     -0.16166667
#> 5  Doug 0.68 0.09 0.54      0.12166667     -0.31666667     -0.06166667
#> 6   Tom 0.91 0.67 0.92      0.35166667      0.26333333      0.31833333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

We could use `across`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-User, ~. -mean(.), .names = "{.col}_DISTfromMEAN"))
```

```
   User   V1   V2   V3 V1_DISTfromMEAN V2_DISTfromMEAN V3_DISTfromMEAN
1   Jim 0.34 0.33 0.88     -0.21833333     -0.07666667      0.27833333
2 David 0.54 0.34 0.71     -0.01833333     -0.06666667      0.10833333
3 Scott 0.12 0.25 0.12     -0.43833333     -0.15666667     -0.48166667
4 Frank 0.76 0.76 0.44      0.20166667      0.35333333     -0.16166667
5  Doug 0.68 0.09 0.54      0.12166667     -0.31666667     -0.06166667
6   Tom 0.91 0.67 0.92      0.35166667      0.26333333      0.31833333
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers1

Comment: Just curious: What is the difference between this solution and the one given by @PaulS?

Comment: In essence nothing. Both very approximately at the same time. Therefore I left this answer. Maybe using `-User` is more intuitive for the OP. But `-1` is also good as we know. I hope this is OK?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  User = c("Jim", "David", "Scott", "Frank", "Doug", "Tom"),
  V1 = c(0.34, 0.54, 0.12, 0.76, 0.68, 0.91),
  V2 = c(0.33, 0.34, 0.25, 0.76, 0.09, 0.67),
  V3 = c(0.88, 0.71, 0.12, 0.44, 0.54, 0.92)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, ~ .x - mean(.x), .names = "{.col}_DISTfromMEAN"))

#>    User   V1   V2   V3 V1_DISTfromMEAN V2_DISTfromMEAN V3_DISTfromMEAN
#> 1   Jim 0.34 0.33 0.88     -0.21833333     -0.07666667      0.27833333
#> 2 David 0.54 0.34 0.71     -0.01833333     -0.06666667      0.10833333
#> 3 Scott 0.12 0.25 0.12     -0.43833333     -0.15666667     -0.48166667
#> 4 Frank 0.76 0.76 0.44      0.20166667      0.35333333     -0.16166667
#> 5  Doug 0.68 0.09 0.54      0.12166667     -0.31666667     -0.06166667
#> 6   Tom 0.91 0.67 0.92      0.35166667      0.26333333      0.31833333
```